# Django REST, multiple querysets in one GET

Tags: django, api, rest

I have the following two models:

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Project(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = None)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'projects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name




class Userproject(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey('Project', on_delete = models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null = True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'UserProjects'
    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

The Userprojects 'user' and 'project' field point to the Usermodel and the Projectmodel above.

Right now I have this view:

```
class GetUserDataByNameView(
    APIView,
):
    def get(self, request, username):
        if User.objects.filter(username = username).exists():
            uid = User.objects.get(username = username).id
            queryset = Userproject.objects.filter(user_id = uid)
            readSerializer = GetUserDataSerializer(queryset, many = True)
            return Response(readSerializer.data)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data":"no user with this username"}, status = 200)
```

and this serializers

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Project
from .models import Userproject

class ProjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length = 500, required = True)
    descriptor = serializers.CharField(max_length = 1000,  default = None)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ['name','descriptor',]


class UserprojectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Userproject
        fields = '__all__'
```

So when the frontend passes the username in the url, I send back this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "id": 16,
        "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:05:03.757807Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:05:03.762307Z",
        "user": 3,
        "project": 50
    },
    {
        "id": 17,
        "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:27:59.938422Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:27:59.945439Z",
        "user": 3,
        "project": 51
    }
]
```

I need to include a reference to the Project model in this queryset and I heard that a Serializer method is what I need.
But trying this serializer does not work and gives me an Attribute Error

```
class GetUserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    projects = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Userproject
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_projects(self, obj):
        data = ProjectSerializer(obj.Project.all(), many = True).data
        return data
```

The error is the following:

```
'Userproject' object has no attribute 'Project'
```

What I want to achieve is something that includes the project model with the given Project ID (called just project in the json)for example like this:

```
{
        "id": 17,
        "created_at": "2021-10-20T16:27:59.938422Z",
        "updated_at": "2021-10-20T16:27:59.945439Z",
        "user": 3,
        "project": 51
        {
         projectname : ...
         projectdescriptor: ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to return multiple projects? Each `Userproject` only has one related `Project`?

Comment: I indeed do not try to do this. How would you adapt this to only show the project with the correct ID?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your question correctly but the below should set you on the right path.

From your view or anywhere you are calling the UserProfile, you should go about it this way,

```
#provided username is unique in your models.
class GetUserDataByNameView(
    APIView,
):
    def get(self, request, username):
        try:
            uid = User.objects.only('id').get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data":"no user with this username"}, status = 200)

         queryset = Userproject.objects.select_related('project').filter(user_id=uid.id)
         readSerializer = GetUserDataSerializer(queryset, many = True)
         return Response(readSerializer.data)
```

Then in your serializer, you should do,

```
class GetUserDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    projects = serializers.SerializerMethodField(source='get_projects')

    class Meta:
        model = Userproject
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_projects(self, obj):
        serial_proj = ProjectSerializer(obj.project)
        return serial_proj.data
```